# Can't read file generated by bash line

Tags: c, linux, bash

I have written a C code where the bash script lines are used inside this C code, and this is how I wrote it:

```
printf("wc -l < smallerthan > number_lines\n");   
if( (fr=fopen(fname_rcut,"r"))==NULL )  {  printf("error in rcut file:   %s\n",fname_rcut);  exit(1);  }
```

I need to read the file "number_lines" which is generated from "smallerthan" file, the problem is when I source the C code to run automatically like:

```
$gcc myC_code.c -lm     
$./a.out > run.sh  
$source run.sh
```

Then if I view the `run.sh`

```
& vi run.sh
```

I get this inside `run.sh`:

```
    wc -l < smallerthan > number_lines  
    ls 

    error in rcut file: /home/number_lines
```

which mean the code upto this point didn't find my "number_lines" file yet since the number_lines file is yet to appear, but if I copy the line and run it separately, instead of "automatically", then it works because the file is there now.

My question is, how to make my code run automatically and my C code to read the file   which is generated by bash line or how to generate the file and read it properly?

Any idea please because I'm really new to programming and I have to use bash inside C for my work.

Note: the above is only small part of my C code but I used several bash lines inside my C code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of observations in your code. I assume that `char *fname_rcut` indeed points to `"/home/number_lines"`.

First observation: if you write commands to a file, they will not be executed.So the file `number_lines` is created only after you run `run.sh`. Therefore, the file will not exist during the execution of your C program. You might look into `int system(const char *command)` (`man 3 system`).

Second observation: `/home/number_lines` is probably not the correct filename. It would probably be `/home/your_name/number_lines`; try a `pwd` to see what the exact directory name is.

Third observation: Why do you want to `source run.sh`? Source executes the file in the current shell. There is usually no need for that.

Comment: the directory is right i just deleted to decrease the info and wriritng, bit thats true the second observation my file still not avilabe when i run the code , so what else i shall do before any command i shall do ? for the source this command i knew to run C code includes bash lines do you suggest any method ? so my question how to solve this issue keeping using this bash line to generate the number_lines file and run all code automatically

Comment: another i did "source " to run all bash lines included in the C. code file , this is not onley my code " its quite big" but what i do usually is converting nd soring datats etc. but the problem appeared when i started to read the "number_lines" file which is still not generated

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it :
what we need actually is using system(command) after each shell command
for example :

```
printf("wc -l < smallerthan > number_lines\n");
```

will be after solving :

```
sprintf(command1,"wc -l < smallerthan > number_lines\n");  
system(command1);
```